# Using pgfplots, is there a way to get the same data range for two plots in different figures without entering the bounds manually?

Tags: pgfplots

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table {
    0 0
    1 0
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Figure 1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table {
    0 1
    1 1
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Figure 2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Here, the first plot ends up with the y range [-1, 1] while the second plot ends up with the y range [-0.8, 1.2]. I want both plots to have the same range that automatically covers both lines.

How can I do this without entering ymin/ymax manually?

Comment: You could set a style, something like `\pgfplotsset{mystyle/.style={ymin=-2,ymax=2}}` and then use `\begin{axis}[mystyle]` but perhaps this is too manual?

Comment: Your title refers to `scale`, but the question seems to be about the `domain`. Please change one of them so we know which one you are referring to.

Comment: @PeterGrill I changed the title of the question. Seems like the pgfplots manual calls it the "data range", so that's what I changed it to. Thanks.

Comment: @cmhughes Yes, I was looking for a solution where the range is still calculated automatically based on the data (as it is usually done if you don't specify anything).

Answer (score 1):

My solution that seems to work so far is to input both data sets to both plots, but only draw one of them in each plot using the options `[draw=none, forget plot]` like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
    0 0
    1 0
}\tableA

\pgfplotstableread{
    0 1
    1 1
}\tableB

\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table {\tableA};
\addplot [draw=none, forget plot] table {\tableB};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Foo}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot [draw=none, forget plot] table {\tableA};
\addplot table {\tableB};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Bar}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Foobar}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I also changed the example slightly to put the graphs side-by-side, since that's what I wanted this for in the first place (for easier comparisons of two non-overlaid graphs).

[image]